# In Graphviz, can I adjust arrow pointing to rectangle's boundary?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Can I adjust arrow pointing to rectangle's boundary? I want to describe a stack pointer. Thanks! 
Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a port. For example:

```
sp->stack:sw;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to use [HTML-like-labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

```
digraph structs {
    node [shape=plaintext]
    stack [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="top">top</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="mid">middle</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="bot">bottom</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>];
    // edge to stack bottom west
    sp -> stack:bot:w
}
```

[image]